# Eclipse: reference sources from other project

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I've got two projects in Eclipse. Both have some source files, and I want to reference sources from one project in another one. The only thing that works is

```
Project Properties -> Java build path -> Projects
```

Where I add the required project.

The problem is that when I'm trying to launch the project1 activity it starts and then launches project2 default activity.

How could I add sources from another project?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use another project as an library in your Android project add the project via Project Properties --> Android --> Library. The referenced project should be marked 'Is Library' on their own properties page.